# Unable to print specific field in json body

Tags: python, json

I need to print the field named `"payment_intent"` in my JSON body. I am currently unsuccesful in doing so. It seems like i'm requesting the right parameter.

I've tried like this

```
payment_intent = event['data']['object']['payment_intent']
```

My JSON body:

```
{
  "object": {
    "id": "",
    "object": "payment_intent",
    "amount": 100,
    "amount_capturable": 0,
    "amount_received": 100,
    "application": null,
    "application_fee_amount": null,
    "canceled_at": null,
    "cancellation_reason": null,
    "capture_method": "automatic",
    "charges": {
      "object": "list",
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "",
          "object": "charge",
          "amount": 100,
          "amount_refunded": 0,
          "application": null,
          "application_fee": null,
          "application_fee_amount": null,
          "balance_transaction": "",
          "billing_details": {
            "address": {
              "city": null,
              "country": "",
              "line1": null,
              "line2": null,
              "postal_code": null,
              "state": null
            },
            "email": "",
            "name": "",
            "phone": null
          },
          "captured": true,
          "created": 1554414723,
          "currency": "usd",
          "customer": "",
          "description": null,
          "destination": null,
          "dispute": null,
          "failure_code": null,
          "failure_message": null,
          "fraud_details": {
          },
          "invoice": null,
          "livemode": true,
          "metadata": {
          },
          "on_behalf_of": null,
          "order": null,
          "outcome": {
            "network_status": "approved_by_network",
            "reason": null,
            "risk_level": "normal",
            "seller_message": "Payment complete.",
            "type": "authorized"
          },
          "paid": true,
          "payment_intent": "pi_1ELdTCB2MQ8LEk6k2PTkpRd0",
          "payment_method_details": {
            "card": {
              "brand": "visa",
              "checks": {
                "address_line1_check": null,
                "address_postal_code_check": null,
                "cvc_check": "pass"
              },
              "country": "DK",
              "exp_month": ,
              "exp_year": ,
              "fingerprint": "",
              "funding": "",
              "last4": "",
              "three_d_secure": null,
              "wallet": null
            },
            "type": "card"
          },
          "receipt_email": "",
          "receipt_number": "1308-6739",
          "receipt_url": "",
          "refunded": false,
          "refunds": {
            "object": "list",
            "data": [
            ],
            "has_more": false,
            "total_count": 0,
            "url": "/v1/charges/ch_1ELdTbB2MQ8LEk6kOQQd5T9n/refunds"
          },
          "review": null,
          "shipping": null,
          "source": {
            "id": "",
            "object": "source",
            "amount": null,
            "card": {
              "exp_month": ,
              "exp_year": ,
              "last4": "",
              "country": "",
              "brand": "",
              "cvc_check": "",
              "funding": "debit",
              "fingerprint": "",
              "three_d_secure": "optional",
              "name": null,
              "address_line1_check": null,
              "address_zip_check": null,
              "tokenization_method": null,
              "dynamic_last4": null
            },
            "client_secret": "",
            "created": 15,
            "currency": null,
            "customer": "",
            "flow": "none",
            "livemode": true,
            "metadata": {
            },
            "owner": {
              "address": {
                "city": null,
                "country": "DK",
                "line1": null,
                "line2": null,
                "postal_code": null,
                "state": null
              },
              "email": "",
              "name": "",
              "phone": null,
              "verified_address": null,
              "verified_email": null,
              "verified_name": null,
              "verified_phone": null
            },
            "statement_descriptor": null,
            "status": "chargeable",
            "type": "card",
            "usage": "reusable"
          },
          "source_transfer": null,
          "statement_descriptor": null,
          "status": "succeeded",
          "transfer_data": null,
          "transfer_group": null
        }
      ],
      "has_more": false,
      "total_count": 1,
      "url": "/v1/charges?payment_intent=pi_1ELdTCB2MQ8LEk6k2PTkpqweEwwRd0"
    },
    "confirmation_method": "automatic",
    "created": 1554414698,
    "currency": "usd",
    "customer": "",
    "description": null,
    "last_payment_error": null,
    "livemode": true,
    "metadata": {
    },
    "next_action": null,
    "on_behalf_of": null,
    "payment_method_types": [
      "card"
    ],
    "receipt_email": null,
    "review": null,
    "shipping": null,
    "source": "",
    "statement_descriptor": null,
    "status": "succeeded",
    "transfer_data": null,
    "transfer_group": null
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you traverse through wrong path for printing such a param. By the way it is hard to say with these info that you provided in the question. Be more specific if you can and put more detail.

Comment: If you're thinking about where `event` comes from, then I can confirm that it's not thats whats causing the issue. The issue lies in the wrong path as you mentioned. I'm just not sure how to move into the correct path. Never really used JSON before.

Comment: Is `event` root of the json object? if so, then you have to print something like this: event["object"]["charges"]["data"][0]["payment_intent"]

Comment: use `print()` to test every element - `print(event)`, next `print(event['data'])`, next `print(event['data']['object'])`. You can also use `type()` to see if you have dictionary or list - ie. `print( type(event['data']) )`. If you have dictionary then you can use `.keys()` to see keys in dictionary - ie. `print( event['data'].keys() )`. If you have list then you have to use `[0]` o test first element. ie. type `print( type(event['object']['charges']['data'][0]) )` and keys `print( event['object']['charges']['data'][0].keys() )`